# maximal slope of subbundles of a vector bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a non-singular surface over an algebraically closed field, $E$ a $\mu$-stable vector bundle of rank $r$ on $X$ w.r.t. an ample $H$. We know that for all proper coherent subsheaves $F\subset E$ with rk($F$)<rk($E$), we have $\mu(F)<\mu(E)$.

If we consider the subsheaves $E'\subset E$ with rk($E'$)=rk($E$), then $E/E'$ is a torsion sheaf and we will find that

> a) If dim Supp($E/E'$)=0, then $(E')^{\vee\vee}\cong E$ and $\mu(E')=\mu(E)$,
>
> b) If dim Supp($E/E'$)$\geq 1$, then $\mu(E')<\mu(E)$.

My question is, if $F$ is a proper coherent subsheaf with maximal slope, but not the case of a), can we claim that rk($F$)<rk($E$)?

Comment: Do you mean that $E/E'$ is a torsion sheaf on a surface wwith $c_1(E/E')=0?

Comment: @Kapil Yes, in the case a), $c_1(E/E')=0$. My question is, if we consider all coherent subsheaf of $E$ except the case of a), and find $F$ which has maximal slope, do we have rk($F$)<rk($E$)?